# Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I know there are a lot of topics about this subject, but none of them will fix my problem.

> Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

**Login.php:**

```
require_once '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'appid',
  'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'user_friends', 'user_location']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://website.com/login-callback.php', $permissions);
```

**Login-callback.php:**

```
include("library/config.php");
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'appid',
  'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,birthday,email,link,gender,locale,verified,friends,location', $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    //echo $response->getGraphUser();
    $user = $response->getGraphUser();

    $_SESSION['facebook_uid'] = $user->getId();

    /* Do Login Things -> Database update etc. */

    header("Location: /");
}
```

I really don't know how to fix the error.

Comment: Is it possible you include your login.php more than once during the process, or that you are calling the getLoginUrl method more than once? (It creates a new state value in the session on each execution.)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
session_start();
```

in both files before using fb classes

Comment: Please try to explain why this could help the OP and probably provide a reference backing up your claim.